# Script run using systemd service before shutdown takes too long and doesn't finish

Tags: bash, shutdown, systemd

I have successfully created a service in systemd that runs a script just before server shutdown/reboot. But the problem is that my script takes too long to execute (around 3-4 minutes) and the server shuts down before it is finished. Debug log indicates that the script is indeed running but it is stopped halfway.

Here are my two different ways of implementing this service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Stop Service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/home/user/stop-service.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and

```
[Unit]
Description=Stop Service
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=final.target


[Service]
ExecStart=/home/user/stop-service.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=final.target
```

They both successfully call `stop-service.sh` but the script takes too long to run. Is there any way to make sure `stop-service.sh` finishes running before server is fully shut down?

My server is RHEL7.

Comment: It may be useful to add the relevant section of the log in your question

Answer (score 3):

I found a way that works for me:

```
[Unit]
Description=Stop Service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/home/user/stop-service.sh
TimeoutStopSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

According to my research, the systemd service has a default 90 seconds wait time for each service to run their stop command (ExecStop) before sending the terminal signal. TimeoutStopSec=300 will set the wait time to 5 minutes for that one particular service.

If you want to change the default wait time, you can locate the file /etc/systemd/system.conf and modify the value of DefaultTimeoutStopSec, then reload the daemon with

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

to load the new value.